# I am using AngularJs 1.2.23 and getting an error - component is not a function

Tags: angularjs

In angularjs using component features and getting an error message.

> Error Message - component is not a function.

And the reference URL is https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03

Comment: Hey neel, it's impossible to tell the problem based on the information you've supplied.  Can you elaborate by adding the bits of code, or better yet providing a reproducible example?

Comment: Components feature were introduced to angularjs in version 1.5 and above.